# File writing statement does not work properly

Tags: c#, file, file-io, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

I have the following function:

```
static public void logEntry( string expression, string result )
{
    string content = expression + "=" + result + "\n";
    if (!logFileExists()) File.Create( logFileName );
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( logFileName );
    sw.Write( content );
    sw.Close();
}
```

...after these three calls:

```
logEntry( "3/2", "1.5");
logEntry( "8/2", "4");
logEntry( "10/2", "5");
```

my file looks like this:

```
10/2=5
```

instead of this:

```
3/2=1.5
8/2=4
10/2=5
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) constructor overload that appends if the file exist

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( logFileName, true ))
{
     sw.Write( content );
}
```

Also, if the file doesn't exists, this constructor creates a new file, thus, the call to File.Create is not necessary.